# Probability - "tetrahedronal cube" - Probabiltiy that a number is a perfect cube - sample space

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We "roll" a tetrahedron with the integers from 1 to 4 written on its faces three times.
>
> What is the probability that the product of the  numbers we got is a perfect cube given that there is a 4 in at least one roll?

As for the main part of the exercise, there are 7 outcomes that meet our criteria, because 8 = 4 x 2 x 1 (3! possibilities) and 64 = 4 x 4 x 4 (1 possibility)

Now, as for the sample space, I am really puzzled. I tried to do it like that:

$\Omega=4*4*3!$, but that counts some possibilities twice. I even went to great lengths and counted them manually - I got 37 possible outcomes. 
Could you explain to me the right way to get this number in a trifle less tedious way?

Comment: By "a tetrahedron with the integers from 1 to 4 written on its faces three times", do you mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:4-sided_dice_250.jpg ?

Answer (score 2):

There are $4*4*4$ possible outcomes total. Of those, $3*3*3$ do not include a $4$.

You could also do this by using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but only if you're feeling masochistic.